# Searching an array list of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

How would I search for the employee "Tim"?

```
ArrayList <ClassName> employee = new ArrayList <ClassName>();
   employee.add(new ClassName("Name","Department",phoneNumber,"address")); 
   employee.add(new ClassName("Tim","something",9803845994,"something St"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 :** Loop through the ArrayList to find the employee

```
  for(ClassName emp :  enployee)
  {
      if("Tim".equals(emp.getName()))
      {
           // do something
           break;
      }
  }
```

**Option 2 :** Store the employees in some fast searchable data structure like a HashMap

```
  Map<String, ClassName> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();
  employeeMap.add("Tim",  new ClassName("Tim","something",9803845994,"something St"));
  employeeMap.add("Jack",  new ClassName("Jack","something",22222222,"something St"));
```

No searching is very simple

```
  Employee emp = employeeMap.get("Tim");
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out Option 2 only works if the employee name is distinct, as in adding another Tim will overwrite the other one